# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "this.hotelsLink" is null Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I try to do some tests using Selenium, but I can't test what I do

HomePage.java

```
package PageObject;

import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.FindBy;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.DefaultUrl;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

@DefaultUrl("page:homepage")
public class Homepage extends PageObject {
      //Menu
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"fadein\"]/header/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[1]/a")
    WebElement homeLInks;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Hotels']//span[text()='Hotels   ']")
    WebElement hotelsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Travelstart']//span[text()='Flights  ']")
    WebElement flightsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Tours']//span[text()='Tours    ']")
    WebElement toursLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Cars']//span[text()='Cars     ']")
    WebElement carsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Offers']//span[text()='Offers   ']")
    WebElement offersLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Ivisa']//span[text()='c']")
    WebElement visaLink;

   public void checkLink(){
        hotelsLink.click();
    }
}
```

Hooks.java

```
import PageObject.Homepage;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Hooks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://phptravels.net/");

       Homepage homepage = new Homepage();
       homepage.checkLink();
    }
}
```

Error:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 38072
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Apr 27, 2022 2:46:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Apr 27, 2022 2:46:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 101, so returning the closest version found: 99
Apr 27, 2022 2:46:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 101 of 99
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "this.hotelsLink" is null
at PageObject.Homepage.checkCookie(Homepage.java:73)
at Hooks.main(Hooks.java:19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see the following issues:

1. It seems you didn't pass driver instance to HomePage?
2. This line is not needed - *System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");*
3. The hotelsLink locator seems incorrect.

   ```
   package PageObject;

   import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.FindBy;
   import net.thucydides.core.annotations.DefaultUrl;
   import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

   @DefaultUrl("page:homepage")
   public class Homepage extends PageObject {
      //Menu
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"fadein\"]/header/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[1]/a")
    WebElement homeLInks;
    @FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(.,'Hotels')]")
    WebElement hotelsLink;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Travelstart']//span[text()='Flights  ']")
    WebElement flightsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Tours']//span[text()='Tours    ']")
    WebElement toursLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Cars']//span[text()='Cars     ']")
    WebElement carsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Offers']//span[text()='Offers   ']")
    WebElement offersLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Ivisa']//span[text()='c']")
    WebElement visaLink;

   public Homepage(WebDriver driver) {
       super(driver);//In case you want to pass the driver instance to super class
       PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
   }

   public void checkLink(){
        hotelsLink.click();
    }
   ```

   }

Hooks.java

```
import PageObject.Homepage;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Hooks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://phptravels.net/");

       Homepage homepage = new Homepage(driver);
       homepage.checkLink();
    }
}
```

Execution Result:
I made the above changes and its working fine for me.
(Note: I have removed PageObjects class and some Serenity imports as you didn't share them)
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The error is not displayed, but the "click" doesn't work. Practically, is displayed on the Homepage and this is all process, the program doesn't make click on the Hotels link from the menu.